# Jackson JsonProperty not applied

Tags: jackson2

Hello I have read many of the StackOverflow pages but not found a solution for the problem.

Example:

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class A {
   @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
   private int var1;
   @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
   private B var2;
}

@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class B {
   @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
   private String bar1;
   @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
   @JsonProperty("bar4")
   private String bar2;
}
```

I have removed the get/set methods for more clear.

I have tried to remane bar2 by putting @JsonProperty on the field and on the setter and there was no effect. I use Jackson 2.8.8.
I also tried @JsonGetter but no result.

Comment: how did you find it's not working ?

Comment: This is an example. At work I tried to make a field to be remaned when serialized from 'bar2' to 'bar-2' and it did not work. Then I tried to change it from 'bar2' to 'bar4' and also did not work.